# Export Shapefile with UTF-8 encoding for non-english characters in GeoPandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, encoding

This part of code puts the `EΞ` characters in a column and when exported it shows `??` in their place.

```
dff['KAEK']=dff['CAD'].str[:5].add('ΕΞ').add(dff['CAD_AD_F'].str[5:]).add(dff['rank'])
dff.to_file(out)
```

Where can i set the `utf-8`?

Comment: Can you make a working self-contained minimal example please? It shouldn't be too many lines, just enough to create a GeoPandas array with one or two features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `dff. to_file(out,encoding='')`and where is the encoding try your language specific versions until you find it.

Comment: I'd still like to see a fully working example of this because I can't make this work if I put some non-ascii strings into a pandas df.

Comment: dff.to_file('out.shp',encoding='UTF-8') should solve for most cases